# Is "Cucumber With Selenium" support for mobile and web environment Integration?

Tags: selenium, web, mobile, cucumber

In my application, we want to test BDD for "mobile verification step" from web application page with cucumber and selenium?

**Scenario:** Getting Passcode from mobile and enter into my web application page

Is any process we need to configure  for this application.

Thanks,

Comment: Maybe look at appium to conect to the mobile to get the password and pass it to selenium to enter into the web app...

Comment: Thanks for your reply.